# Katalon Studio best logging practices

Tags: logging, katalon-studio

I want to know what the best practice is for logging since I have a common test case from which I call other specific test cases, I don't like having a `KeywordLogger` or `KeywordUtil` object in each class. Should I just use `KeywordUtil.LOGGER` instead of making a reference object?

I am new to Katalon Studio, so it would be great if someone could give their perspective on this. Is there a conventional way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a best practice for logging. It would heavily depend on your use cases.

Katalon Studio by default generates [**logs**](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/viewing_execution_logs.html#standard-view-vs-tree-view) for individual **test cases**, and [**test reports**](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/tutorials/viewing_test_suite_reports.html#report-overview) (in `.csv`, `.html`, `.log` and `.xml` formats) for **test suites**.

As you have already said, you can integrate the logger, as discussed [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/how-can-i-integrate-logger-in-katelon-studio/14107) and [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/write-execution-log-report-to-file/9541) on Katalon forums, and add it into a `.properties` file:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.Append=false
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:(%F:%L) - %m%n
```

and then after setting path of config file to

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("path of .properties file")
```

And, of course, the most custom way is to create your own logging and reporting [framework](https://forum.katalon.com/t/how-to-customize-report-generation/6152/8).